# Raise tapped event windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-rt

I need to open a ComboBox when the user perform a tap on a button, any idea?
I have searched a lot but I haven't find useful stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true);
}
```

Comment: i don't have enough reputation sorry